# warning: useless type name in empty declaration

Tags: c, gcc, warnings, typedef, extern

I have a project and two files in the project are named as `query-structures.h` `query-structures.c`. Contents in the `query-structures.h` are

```
#include <stdint.h>
typedef struct user_identifier user_identifier;
extern user_identifier;
```

and in `query-structures.c` are

```
#include "query-structures.h"
struct user_identifier
{
    uint64_t user_id;
};
```

Now the Compiler is giving me a warning as

`warning: useless type name in empty declaration [enabled by default]`

I cannot understand why this warning is there because I have to use this `struct` in other files of my project.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This line is abnormal because you declare a type but no variable name

```
extern user_identifier;
```

For example, with ints, you would write

```
extern int x;
```

not

```
  extern int;
```